# Анимация кнопки в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

В общем делаю небольшую игру на tkinter чисто для опыта в написании кода, но вот завис на том, что не могу сделать нормальную анимацию для кнопки. Есть кнопка, которая сделана в виде картинки. После нажатия на нее, функция `start_btn_anim` делает свое дело и спрайт кнопки меняется на "вдавленную". Но при этом, дальше кнопка так и остается вдавленной, а я бы хотел, что бы она возвращалась к исходному положению. Помогите, кто знает. Какие-то еще профессиональные правки в коде тоже было бы классно почитать, я лишь новичок.

Вот код самой игры:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Tk, Button
import PIL
from PIL import ImageTk

#---MAIN MENU---#
class Main_menu(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        #Стили для всего текста в главном меню#                    
        self.lbl_style = ttk.Style()
        
        self.lbl_style.configure("TLabel", 
                                 font = ("KenVector Future Thin", 80, "bold"))
        #-------------------------------------#
        
        #ВИДЖЕТЫ И ИХ РАЗМЕЩЕНИЕ#
        self.logo = ttk.Label(self,
                              text = "SFS") #Логотип#
                         
        self.logo.place(relx=.505,
                        rely=.25,
                        anchor="n")
        
        self.version = ttk.Label(self,
                                 text = "v0.0.1",
                                 font = ("KenVector Future Thin", 12)) #Версия#
        
        self.version.place(x = 0,
                           y = 0)  

        self.start_btn_sprite = PhotoImage(file = r"C:\Users\Вадим\Desktop\игра\sprites\PNG\grey_button01.png")
        self.pressed_start_btn_sprite = PhotoImage(file = r"C:\Users\Вадим\Desktop\игра\sprites\PNG\grey_button02.png")
        
        self.start_btn = Button(self,
                                    text = "NEW GAME",
                                    image = self.start_btn_sprite)
                                    
        self.start_btn["border"] = "0"
        
        def start_btn_anim(event):
            self.start_btn.configure(image = self.pressed_start_btn_sprite)
            
        self.start_btn.bind('<Button-1>', start_btn_anim)
                                                                       
        self.start_btn.place(relx=.5,
                             rely=.4,
                             anchor="n")
        
        self.options_btn = Button(self,
                                      text = "OPTIONS",
                                      image = self.start_btn_sprite)
        self.options_btn["border"] = "0"                              
                                      
        self.options_btn.place(relx=.5,
                               rely=.45,
                               anchor="n")
        
        self.exit_btn = Button(self,
                                   text = "EXIT",
                                   image = self.start_btn_sprite,
                                   command = self.quit)
        self.exit_btn["border"] = "0"
                                   
        self.exit_btn.place(relx=.5,
                            rely=.5,
                            anchor="n")
        #-----------------------#
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_menu = Main_menu()
    main_menu.geometry("1080x720")
    main_menu.resizable(height = False, width = False)
    main_menu.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    main_menu.overrideredirect(True)
    main_menu.mainloop()
#---------------#
```

Comment: Функцию к кнопке нужно привязывать не через bind, а через параметр command, тогда не будет "западать"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для обработки нажатия кнопки мышью нужно использовать параметр `command`, а не `bind`. Привязка через `bind` к событию клика мыши на кнопке приводит к эффекту "залипания" кнопки.

Варианты исправления:

```
# 1 вариант - изменения command через метод config

self.start_btn = Button(self,
                            text = "NEW GAME",
                            image = self.start_btn_sprite)
                            
self.start_btn["border"] = "0"

def start_btn_anim(event):
    self.start_btn.configure(image = self.pressed_start_btn_sprite)
    
self.start_btn.config(command=start_btn_anim)
```

```
# 2 вариант - указание command сразу при создании

def start_btn_anim(event):
    self.start_btn.configure(image = self.pressed_start_btn_sprite)

self.start_btn = Button(self,
                            text = "NEW GAME",
                            image = self.start_btn_sprite
                            command=start_btn_anim)
                            
self.start_btn["border"] = "0"
```

---

По самому коду особых комментариев нет, поэтому по стилю кода:

1. [По pep8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#class-names) классы нужно называть с большой буквы каждое слово без разделения слов подчеркиваниями: `MainMenu`
2. Выше и ниже класса или отдельной функции должно быть по две пустых строки (опять же, по pep8: см. [Blank lines](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#blank-lines)). У вас сразу выше и ниже класса идут отделяющие комментарии. Комментарий "MAIN MENU" перед классом `Main_menu` - мягко говоря избыточный)
3. Отступы при переносе параметров функций на другую строку. Тут вот такой вариант правильный ([с точки зрения pep8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#indentation)):

```
self.version = ttk.Label(self,
                         text="v0.0.1",
                         font=("KenVector Future Thin", 12))
```

только пробелов слева и справа от "равно" тут не должно быть (когда это передача параметров или указание значений по умолчанию для парамеров функции, при условии, что нет аннотации кода) - см. [pep8 - Other Recommendation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#other-recommendations) начиная со слов "Don’t use spaces around the = sign".

Вот такой вариант уже не правильный (все параметры визуально должны начинаться на одном уровне):

```
self.start_btn = Button(self,
                            text = "NEW GAME",
                            image = self.start_btn_sprite
                            command=start_btn_anim)
```

Правильно было бы так быть так:

```
self.start_btn = Button(self,
                        text="NEW GAME",
                        image=self.start_btn_sprite
                        command=start_btn_anim)
```

Я предпочитаю такой стиль:

```
self.start_btn = Button(
    self,
    text="NEW GAME",
    image=self.start_btn_sprite
    command=start_btn_anim
)
```

- это соответствует pep8, код становится не таким широким, не нужно каждый раз поправлять отступы, когда переименовываешь переменную, плюс все такие вызовы выглядят единообразно, с одинаковым отступом слева у параметров.

В принципе, если работаете в PyCharm, то он вам все несоответствия как предупреждения подчеркнет.

Также можно использовать какой-нибудь форматтер, например [black](https://pypi.org/project/black/) ([описание стиля](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/the_black_code_style/current_style.html)), который весь код по своим понятия прекрасного отформатирует (`black` и PyCharm не во всем между собой согласны, но кому-то одному придется уступить).